# In an xsl choose statement how can I test for the value of a js variable

Tags: javascript, html, sharepoint, xslt

I'm working in SharePoint with an xsl file and have an xsl choose statement which i wish to help conditionally display records from my xml. in the code below I test `DAS_ID` to be equal to `*someValue*`

This works if I hardcode a value in such as `<xsl:when test="DAS_ID = 5 ">` but wish to compare the .  What I'm trying to do is replace `*value*` with a javascript variable...or at least the current value of that js variable.  Is this possible? any suggestions?

```
 <xsl:choose>
  <xsl:when test="DAS_ID = *someValue* ">
   <td bgcolor="#ff00ff">
   <xsl:value-of select="HTML_ID"/>
   </td>
  </xsl:when>
<xsl:otherwise>
  <td>not matched</td>
  </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```

Much appreciated,

Comment: In what context? Where is the XSL transform running? Which transform engine?

Comment: To be honsest I am not sure I am relativly new to xsl.  I have the xsl file on a sharepoint site I am working on.

Comment: If the XSL transform is being done on the server you probably do not have access to the js variable; in this scenario the XSL generates HTML (including Javascript) which is sent to the client where the Javascript executes.  Maybe a Sharepoint expert can chime in.  I've added the "sharepoint" tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
What I'm trying to do is replace *value* with a javascript variable...or at least the current value of that js variable. Is this possible? any suggestions?
```

If the Javascript variable is in scope (otherwise the question has no meaning whatsoever) when the XSLT transformation is invoked from the Javascript code, **simply pass the value of the Javascript variable as a parameter to the transformation and access it inside the transformation as an external (global) `xsl:param`.**